# Law of total covariance with multiple conditionals

Tags: variance, expected-value, covariance

The law of total covariance states:

$Cov(X,Y) = E(Cov(X,Y|Z)) + Cov(E(X|Z),E(Y|Z))$

If I condition on another variable $T$, does this still hold? E.g.

$Cov(X,Y) = E(Cov(X,Y|Z,T)) + Cov(E(X|Z,T),E(Y|Z,T))$

Comment: Rename Z in second equation W, then let Z in first equation be Z=(W,T) to get second equation.